# What's the rule for pronouncing similarly-spelt verb conjugations?

Tags: gramática, pronúncia

Recently, while reading through a book written in extremely formal Portuguese, I came across this line:

> Ó, meus amados irmãos, ouvi minhas palavras.

The word in question here is *ouvi*. Normally when I see this word, it is in this context:

> Eu ouvi o que você falou.

I understand the difference in context: the *ouvi* from the first example is an imperative form (assuming it's conjugated to *vós*), while the second example is the past-perfect form.

From context, I feel that the first example should be pronounced similar to *ouve* (as in *Ele ouve*), and the second example with the emphasis on the last syllable (as in many other past-perfect conjugations with verbs ending in *-er* and *-ir*:

```
bater -> bati
sacudir -> sacudi
correr -> corri
comer -> comi
```

My question(s) is(are):

- **Are these two forms pronounced the same way, or are they pronounced differently?**

  - If different, what grammatical or pronunciation rule exists to explain why?

Comment: Why do you feel that the "vós ouvi" command should be pronounced like the "tu ouve" command?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's the exact same pronunciation for both. That's all there is to it, really. All words ending with **i** or **is** and with no accent are stressed in the last syllable.

It’s the same thing with

> Ele **ouve/bate** (present indicative) and **ouve/bate** (tu, imperative)

In Portugal, but not in Brasil, the first person plural of the present and past-perfect indicative of regular verbs ending -*ar* are pronounced differently, but it is optional to spell them same or diffently. For instance:

> *Agora, nós gos**t**amos. Ontem, nós gos**ta**mos* (ptPT and ptBR) or *gos**tá**mos* (ptPT only)

In Portugal, the **ta** is pronounced as **tâ**mara in the present, but as **tá**bua in the past-perfect *even if* you spell it *gostamos*. In Brasil, on the other hand, they're both pronounced as **tâ**mara.

Comment: Don't understand why ANeves deleted his answer. It was correct.

Comment: I was not happy enough with it. :)

Comment: `In regular verbs ending -ar, the first person plural of the presente and past-perfect indicative are spelled the same` [False](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/Conjugar/gostar). Hoje gost**a**mos, ontem gost**á**mos.

Comment: In Brasil it's true. Hoje gost**a**mos, ontem gost**a**mos: spelled **and** pronounced the same.

Comment: You have to be on your toes when @ANeves is around :) _Ontem gostamos/gostámos_. Both spellings are now official in Portugal under the new [Acordo Ortográfico](http://www.portaldalinguaportuguesa.org/acordo.php?action=acordo&version=1990) Base IX 4.

Comment: @Raquel Edit appreciated. I hate to leave a “at least in Portugal” in a post, but often my ignorance leaves me no option. I welcome all clarifications.

Comment: I stand corrected. :) Damned A.O.... now everything I knew is wrong. Not even "pharmácia" is correct any more! :(

Comment: Well, I stand corrected too. I had thought the _gostámos_ had gone for good. My answer is better now.

Answer (score 5):

They're pronounced the same way.

I think that the reason you feel *ouvi (vós)* is pronounced differently is by analogy with the singular: *ouve (tu)* or *ouça (você)* (which are pronounced with stress on the first). But that would go against the general rules of stress in Portuguese, where words ending in `i` need an accent to be paroxytone (e.g. *táxi*).

Exceptions like *ser* aside (*és*/*sê* and *sois*/*sede*), the forms of the imperative are the same as the ones from the present with the final *s* dropped and the final *s* does not affect where the stress falls. So  *(tu) ouves*/*ouve (tu)* are both paroxytone and *(vós) ouvis*/*ouvi (vós)* are both oxytone.

Note that the archaic form of *ouvi (vós)* already has the stress on the syllable with the `i`: *ouvide (vós)*.